# Allow content with $_Session

Tags: php, session, authentication

I've been following some tutorials and managed to get my login and logout scripts working.  What I"m now trying to do it get it to only allow access to pages when the user is logged in.  Right now it's just redirecting users to the login page every time, which tells me that the session isn't being set or or my code is just wrong (and I've tried everything I can think of)

This is the login.php script that my form runs in order to set the session:

```
<?php
// establishing the MySQLi connection
require 'init.php';
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// checking the user
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
    $sel_user = "select * from login where username='$username' AND password='$pass'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_user);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
    if($check_user>0) {
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Sorry.  Your username or password is not correct, try again!')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

And this is what I'm including at the top of every page:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '')) {
    header ("Location: account-login.php");
}

require 'init.php';
?>
```

I switched the login.php file from directing to a page to a popup telling me that I logged in and I get the popup, so the user and password are registering fine, it's just not storing the session somehow.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you starting a session in the login script as well? Doesn't look like it.

Comment: Do you even indent bro?

Comment: Also have you made sure that you have an input in the account-login.php page with name=username and that the form's action is set to login.php?

Comment: Make sure `session_start()` is added to every page you need to use sessions and to be on the safe side declare the session variable/s under `sessions start()` to a normal variable and use that in the if statement, sometimes it bugs out when you use the session variable in the if statement (at least it have for me).

Comment: Visit and use => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php which will throw you a little something ;-) Plus, `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()` just for an added flavor. I hope you're not storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: I have name="username" - the form itself looks like it works.  I put popup windows in login.php to say Success and Fail respectively and when I enter the correct/incorrect password I get the corresponding message.

session_start() is on every page.  That second chunk of code I gave is in my header file across the site.

Jim - Have you got an example by chance?  I'm not following. (I'm new :) )

Comment: Error reporting isn't giving me anything unfortunately.

Comment: Make sure that the columns are long enough to accomodate the password then and is VARCHAR. Some use VARCHAR(20) or similar and is often not long enough. 90% of the time, is what the problem is; I always use VARCHAR(255) right up to the gills. Plus, `if(isset($_POST['login']))` your form does contain a name attribute for it, right and is POST method? Forms default to GET if omitted. Also, that whole conditional is based on it.

Comment: @topher you don't by chance have the header file that is included at the top of every page included in your account-login.php page as well, do you?

Comment: @Fred my submit button has a value and name of "login".  When I remove thesecond block of code above that I have on header.php the login screen lets me by, when I enter the correct password.

@ hRdCoder I do not.  The header include is jsut on the other pages I'm trying to secure.

Comment: What second block of code? You need to be specific. Did you mean `require 'init.php';`? You should add `exit;` after your header also.

Comment: @Fred The code  referenced above that I'm including at the top of every page. <?php 
session_start();
if .....etc...

Comment: @topher perhaps if you have not tried yet, change the '<script>window.open(...etc.' code to a PHP header, i.e. header('Location: index.php');. Also be absolutely sure that you have cookies enabled in your browser.

Comment: What I think is happening is that you have an included header without an `exit;`. Your code will want to continue executing everything below that, regardless. That is also another important factor. So, do `header ("Location: account-login.php"); exit;` and for any other header you may have in other files.

Comment: So, how you making out? Moments of silence at times, can be interpreted as success and having a great time. Or, you're still having problems and trying to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I'm really appreciating all this help guys!  So I tried dropping this onto account-login.php:  "var_dump($_SESSION);" and it tells me it's an undefined variable - which looks like the session just isn't being set.  I'm currently trying to do some reading and see if wamp is just not saving the thing...

Comment: Update to last comment:  I do see a session file in the wamp tmp directory, so I think that's ruled out.

Comment: Try scrapping the JS for the moment and just do plain echos. Then change `if (!(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != ''))` to `if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ echo "Session is set: " . $_SESSION['username']; else{ echo "Session is not set.";}`

Comment: I switched to echo's on the login.php to say Success or Fail and I get success.  I then put the scripts back in and tried the code you provided and I get "Session is not set."

Comment: Something in your included JS is playing havoc/tricks on you then, where something in `index.php` could also playing a role. If that file doesn't also have a sessions conditional check, then that could account for the issues. "index.php" should also contain sessions code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I got it to work finally!

Apart from all the comments (which helped a TON), I also decided to change the name I was setting in $_SESSION.  I think it may be because the session name matched the name or POST data and that eas causing a conflict somewhere.

Changed this:

```
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
```

Which I think conflicted to this:

```
$_SESSION['session_id']=$username;
```

Worked!

THANK YOU!!!!!!!

Comment: Great, but where does `$_SESSION['session_id']` fit into your posted code? If you simply changed it to that, then my guess is that you didn't close/destroy the original session, and was this sitting on the server's cache.